# Revoke read access to the home page doesn't work

Tags: security

I installed a vanilla Sitecore 8.2.5 instance and revoked read access on Home page to extranet/anonymous user.
I logged out from the shell site and hit the home page and I am still able to access it !

Is that the normal behaviour or a bug in Sitecore ? If it's the normal behaviour then how can I secure a page from being accessed by anonymous users ?

Comment: Did you verify the security setting with the access viewer?

Comment: Have you published the home item after applying the security?

Comment: Thanks Artsem, I forgot to publish as I am working on another instance which points to master. Now, I published and I am getting the following "The requested document was not found" instead of access denied

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is a bug in Sitecore 8.2 update 5. It has been fixed in update 6 according to the release notes.

https://dev.sitecore.net/Downloads/Sitecore%20Experience%20Platform/82/Sitecore%20Experience%20Platform%2082%20Update6/Release%20Notes

A hotfix might be available from Sitecore Support with the number 183497.

Answer (score 1):

As @Artsem mentioned, please check if your home node is published or not, but in general here are the steps to secure home node for extranet/anonymous users.

1) Go to security editor and revoke read access for home node for extranet/anonymous user.

2) Go to access viewer and make sure that the permissions are added properly.

3) As @Artsem mentioned, please publish home node.

4) Your home page is secured now.

Please follow the steps, and let me know if this helps.

Thanks,

Comment: Thanks Ankit, now, I published and I am getting the following "The requested document was not found" instead of access denied

Comment: @Arsany- can you mark this answer as accepted, if this works for you?

Comment: While a 404 effectively prevents unauthirozed access it is certainly strange that Sitecore decides to return this status code instead of 403 (access denied). I have the very same problem after an upgrade to 8.2.5 from 7.5.